# Laravel - How to query if an array field in DB contains a value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel-5

I have a field in my model `Person` called `jobs` that I'm casting as an array. `jobs` is an array of ids related to a Jobs table. I want to be able to query Person and return all that have a certain id in their jobs array. I see that Laravel has a `whereIn` clause which checks if a database value is in an array but I need the opposite - to check whether a database array contains a value.

Am I stuck having to use `where('jobs', 'like', '%"' . $job_id . '"%')`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure there's an opposite however if you're simply looking to make the query a bit more reusable, you could make it a local scope by adding this to your Person model:

```
/**
 * Scope a query to only include persons with given job id.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeHasJob($query, $jobId)
{
    return $query->where('jobs', 'like', "%\"{$jobId}\"%");
}
```

*The name of the scope `hasJob` may interfere with the parent QueryBuilder method `has` so you might have to come up with a different name for it.*

Now you can use `Person::hasJob($job->id)`. However rather than storing the job ids in a column as an array, you should consider creating a pivot table to map the relationships between a person and job. You can do this using php artisan:

`php artisan generate:pivot persons jobs` 
`php artisan migrate`

Then you need to add the relationship into your Person model:

```
/**
 * The person's jobs
 */
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job');
}
```

So you can query your Person model by Job like this:

```
Person::whereHas('jobs', function ($query) {
    return $query->whereId($job->id);
});
```

Comment: Didn't know about the `generate:pivot` function, very useful!

Answer (score 18):

> Laravel includes `whereJsonContains():` So your field `jobs` that you
> are casting as an array, that can query as :

```
->whereJsonContains('jobs', 3)
```

> That way worked for me ...

Comment: Very clean. Thank you.

Comment: this only works in database servers like mariaDB, if you use mysql, it doesn't have json support

Comment: This is supported in MySQL 5.7+, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I am adding a little more info to this answer                                                                  The data types have to match:
// [1, 2]
->whereJsonContains('players', 1)   // Works.
->whereJsonContains('players', '1') // Doesn't work.
// ["1", "2"]
->whereJsonContains('players', '1') // Works.
->whereJsonContains('players', 1)   // Doesn't work.                                                                             Courtesy : https://newbedev.com/php-wherejsoncontains-and-with-laravel-example

Answer (score 5):

I am adding a little more info to ***Zubayer Hossain's***  answer

```
The data types have to match:
// [1, 2]
->whereJsonContains('players', 1)   // Works.
->whereJsonContains('players', '1') // Doesn't work.

// ["1", "2"]
->whereJsonContains('players', '1') // Works.
->whereJsonContains('players', 1)   // Doesn't work.
```

***whereJsonContains*** can be used in cases where we need to check if a value matches a json encoded field in our table.

Courtesy : https://newbedev.com/php-wherejsoncontains-and-with-laravel-example

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- If you have a collection of value like this: -->
```

$category_id = 1,2,3,...;
$category_id = $_POST['category_id'];

```
$myArray = explode(',', $category_id); 

<!-- If you already have array data you can pass this to the following query -->
$data = DB::table('tablename')->select('*') ->whereIn('catcode', $myArray)->get();
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: what is `$_POST` in laravel?? Why do you use php core functions while Laravel already has  `Request` to get Get / Post form values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this query.

```
$k = ["359045532","359079612","359079372","359081292","359081052","359086332","359086092","359111892","359111652"];

Modal::whereIn('myitems', $k)->get();
```